# Double division loses decimal places in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

What do I have to do to have more than just one decimal place when dividing floats and doubles.

The code is:

```
   double *dbl; //In fact this is a parameter of the function
   double *kg;
   double total = 41.2;

   *dbl = *kg * 1000.0l / total;
```

In my case, *kg = 2485 and total = 41.2. So, the result should be someting like 60315.5339805. However, I only get 60315.5. What do I have to do in order not to lose the rest of the decimal digits.

I know I can use NSNumber, but when I convert to double using doubleValue, I always get 60315.5.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you loging it?  Some literals only do sig figs.

Comment: How are you setting kg value to 2485? Is that a param?

Comment: Kg gets its value from other operations: metres * width / weight. And yes, I log it, and get all de decimal places, but if I use in another operation, I lose them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
- (void) myFunc:(double *)dbl
{
    double kg = 2485;
    double total = 41.2;
    *dbl = kg * 1000.0l / total;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    double d;
    [self myFunc:&d];
    NSLog(@"%lf",d);
}
```

Comment: Well, if I log d, I get 60315.533981. However, if I do d *= 2, I get 120631. Where did all the decimal digits go?

Comment: You are completely right. It works perfectly. What I get is just the log, not the real value, which has all the decimal places. Thank you both.